# Select option group binding with knockout - not setting initial value

Tags: html, knockout.js

Below is the html definition. knockout doesn't bind/select initial value.
I have to set that explicitly.

```
if($cd.data.deptDiv) {
  $("#mySelection").val($cd.data.deptDiv);
} 

Not sure why?



<select id="mySelection" class="form-control" data-bind="value: deptDiv">
            <option value="">Select department or division...</option>                                   
            <optgroup label="Department" data-bind="foreach: $cd.departments">
                <option data-bind="text: name, value: id"></option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Division" data-bind="foreach: $cd.divisions">
                <option data-bind="text: name, value: id"></option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in pure HTML, you need to use the `selected` value to indicate which option is the initially selected one.  I don't see that you have done that, which is why you end up having to set it with jQuery.  You may also be able to get some more info from [one](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) of [these](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) pages in the Knockout docs.

Comment: Initialize `deptDiv` with one of the values from `departments` or `divisions` in your viewmodel. Don't use jQuery to set the value.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ajameson/c8q4e053/3/

Comment: Tried all the recommended options above and still the same problem. Need to find out something has to do with viewmodel.